# Runtime error appeared after I moved some code to new class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had the code:

```
namespace ShowDiagram1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
         bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("pic1.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Image1.ImageUrl = this.ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");
    }
}
```

It worked okay.
I moved this code to new class

```
 namespace ShowDiagram1
 {
     public class MyDraw : WebForm1
     {
          ...
         bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("pic1.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Image1.ImageUrl = this.ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");
     }
 }
```

Now I have runtime error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 85: Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");

pic1.jpg was created okay.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `bitmap` is not null and `pic1.jpg` stays where you search?

Comment: `Image1` will be null. While you created an object (in order to get the code to compile) you probably didn't initialise it.

Comment: Where is Image1 come from? May be it is undefined object for new class.

Comment: bitmap is certainly not null, because pic1 was created. I checked creation date and time of pic1.jpg.

Comment: Can you just use a breakpoint and mouseover all the objects in that statement to find which one is null?

Comment: Image1 is on the WebForm. It worked before without any initialization. I am puzzled why it is null now. Thanks

Comment: I have runtime error on the line "Image1.ImageUrl=..."

Comment: Are you calling the constructor of the base class from MyDraw?

Comment: Remove `this` from the code line; so it should be `Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");`

Comment: >Are you calling the constructor of the base class from MyDraw?     <br/> Sorry. I am novice and don't understand your question

Comment: I believe that's the id of the image control; check whether id of image control have changed/renamed from Image1 to something different.

Comment: Do you have a constructor in MyDraw like (public MyDraw()"), and are you calling the constructor of the parent class from there with :base()

Comment: Oops. I added "TextBoxDebug.Text += "MyDraw";" and also got the same runtime error. Removing "this" in "this. ResolveUrl.." also does not work.

Comment: >age1 is a control added to your webform so it is null. At least you have to pass it as a parameter      <br/>   Hmm. How?  Image1 in MyDraw class is  visible as "WebForm1.Image1". So it seems it should be known inside of the class.

Comment: I use the following in the main WebForm1 class:     <br/>              MyDraw myDraw = new MyDraw(equipmentChain);
            myDraw.Draw();
Perhpas this is  not correct.

Comment: I think you might be on the wrong track entirely... Why is MyDraw inhering from WebForm1 if you are using it as a member variable?

Comment: If I exclude inhering from WebForm1 I got errors such as  name 'TextBoxDebug' 'Image' does not exist in the current context. Should I pass them as parameter somehow?

Comment: Yes, give up on the inheritance entirely, simply declare them as variables in your MyDraw, and pass them in the constructor.

Comment: Okay. I pass Image1 to myDraw. Now I got error  "The name 'ResolveUrl' does not exist in the current context". If I change the line as follows: Image1.ImageUrl = System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");   <br/> then I got compilation error: Error 5 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveUrl(string)'  I am puzzled because in both source main and myDraw files I have the same "using" lines.

Comment: But MyDraw is no longer of type "Control", so it doesn't inherit any such function. You could pass the result of "ResolveUrl(string)" to MyDraw the same as Image1.

Comment: Yes!! It works now. Many thanks! And I will try base() as in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entire goal of this question was quite vague and should be redefined. If MyDraw was meant to be just a utility class to contain some code, then it should have nothing to do with inheritance and instead the necessary data should be passed in the constructor and stored as variables.

Comment: Nop. I got a lot of compilation errors:  <br/>Invalid token 'base' in class, struct, or interface member declaration      <br/> Type expected<br> The name 'Image1' does not exist in the current context <br> etc

Comment: I found better solution. I do inheritance MyDraw:WebForm. And I pass Image1 as parameter to MyDraw. All works okay. Looks like easiest solution. I don't have problems with lines             bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("pic1.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");  <br/>
 Thanks to everybody!! BTW why line break does not work here?

Comment: @user993354 Edited the answer to better reflect the solution we arrived at in the comments. Feel free to accept it, if the problem is now solved.